# Can I ask about a problem solving approach?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have a question and I have a way of approaching its solution. But I don't know whether that approach is correct or not. So can I ask about whether my approach is correct or not on this site?

Comment: You can ask about your approach on MSE. A full comprehensive attempt with work and inquiry about your approach is more than welcome.

Comment: @Prime https://math.meta.stackexchange.com OR https://meta.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I would post on Mathematics Stack Exchange. I am a frequent there, and this would be more than welcome. I would also search for an answer there before posting, as it would avoid the possibility of a duplicate question and many people have similar questions that can be answered sometimes quite simply. Other times, not, which is where the utility of Mathematics Stack Exchange is quite useful.

Comment: These "approach" questions are not appropriate for Meta Math.SE (and certainly not Meta SE), but for [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) see [ask].

Answer (score 13):

Provided you connect your "approach" to an actual problem to be solved, Math.SE should treat your Question as on-topic ("Is my approach correct?).

However note that the *context* is important.  Readers will not be able to discern whether an approach is "correct" without knowing the problem setup and goal.  For that matter we might want to distinguish the following (related) notions of correctness:

(1) The approach is logically sound/based on proper mathematical reasoning from the problem's setup.

(2) The approach is likely (or sure) to be successful in reaching the problem's goal.

You may have been concerned with issues of (1), but there are cases in which one first explores promising approaches that are proper reasoning only to discover that these approaches (2) can never reach the desired goal.  These situations are particularly interesting, so if you are concerned about that possibility, it is well worth mentioning your suspicions in posting the Question.